# Guaranteed Dispatch Sequence

Tags: reactjs, synchronization, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I’m trying to find something out about redux reducers but I think the terminology might be different since this is JavaScript.

Assuming the following reducer:

```
import {
  ONE,
  TWO,
  THREE
} from "../actions/types";

export default function reducer(state = { /* some init state here */ }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ONE: {
      // this case takes 500ms to finish
      return {...state }
    }
    case TWO: {
       // this case takes 200ms to finish
       return {...state }
    }
    case THREE: {
       // this case takes 100ms to finish
       return {...state }
    }
    default: {
       return {...state }
    }
};
```

If I did the following from an action:

```
dispatch({type: ONE});
dispatch({type: TWO});
dispatch({type: THREE});
```

are they guaranteed to resolve in that order? Meaning, is the state synchronized and “single threaded” ? Or would `case TWO: {}`, for example, fire before `case ONE: {}` completed?

Comment: I would speculate that this would happen in a synchronous manner, because you aren't making any promises or anything to pause the actions in their handlers. Nothing in the provided code suggests to me that they'd finish out of order. Would be interested to see if anyone performs real-world tests on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dispatch` is synchronous by default, so, as long as you don't have async calls in the action creator, they execute in the order they were declared.

In [redux's docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) it is implied that `dispatch()` is synchronous:

> Action creators can also be asynchronous and have side-effects. You
>   can read about async actions in the advanced tutorial to learn how to
>   handle AJAX responses and compose action creators into async control
>   flow.

Comment: Yes, the original `store.dispatch()` function is 100% synchronous, and when it returns the state has been updated.  Any asynchronicity happens if middleware intercept the action and do something different.